# learner doesent work by Decision Tree Classification with R

Tags: r

**I have a training- and a Test-dataset for classification. Both Sets have 30 integer columns, 4 date Columns and 3 String Columns. One of the String Column is the classifire. there is no missing Value.** [data discraptin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCTAO.jpg)
**I can run this script without any Error Message:**

library(rpart)

library(caret)

set.seed(100)

inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = training$target90, p = 0.66, list = FALSE)

trainL <- training[ inTrain,]

trainT <- training[-inTrain,]

#DecisionTreeModel

myRpartModel <- rpart(trainL$target90 ~ ., method = "class", data = trainL)

**these are the result of each part:**

table(training$target90)

   JA  NEIN 

 6051   26377 

 table(trainL$target90)

  JA  NEIN 

3994   17409 

table(trainT$target90)

  JA NEIN 

2057 8968

**But when I want to see the result of my model there is one Error and alle rows belong to one class:**

summary(myRpartModel)

Call:

rpart(formula = trainL$target90 ~ ., data = trainL, method = "class")

  n= 21403 

CP:1

nsplit:0.006843599

rel:0

error:1

xerror:0

xstd:0

  Node number 1: 21403 observations

  predicted class=NEIN  expected loss=0.1866094  P(node) =1

   class counts:  3994    17409

  probabilities: 0.187    0.813

**Do you have any Idea?**

Comment: the same problem by C5.0 funktion